# How to convert raster in Illustrator to link?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I have rasterized an object in Illustrator, so it is embedded. I want to enhance it with photoshop, but I don`t know how to convert it to link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I think I may have worked out what you're trying to do....

You've rasterized a set of objects in Illustrator. When you do this the image shows up as an embedded image in the Links Panel.

You want to alter this set of rater objects with Photoshop.

And you want to convert the embedded image to a linked image in the Links Panel.

Correct?

Simply select and copy the raster objects. 
Open Photoshop and paste.  
Alter your image however you want. 
Save the raster image in Photoshop. 
Return to Illustrator 
Highlight the embedded image in the Links Panel  
Choose Relink Image from the Link Panel menu 
Choose your saved Photoshop image

That should replace the rasterized embedded image with a link to the Photoshop image.

Comment: Yes, thats good, but Its sometimes better not to embed you images, live them linked, work with the file that is linked in Photoshop and then as you "Save" your file in Photoshop it updates automataticly in Illustrator, or an alternative would be to use Smart Objects http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wnPrZZ1e0Zg . Do not rasterize them especially if the file is for print, you might lose from the original image quality sometimes...